# What is the maximum number of people/client/computers logged into the same Gmail account at the same time?

Tags: gmail

What is the maximum number of clients logged into the same Gmail account at the same time?
Also what is the limit for logging frequently from different places

Comment: "limit for logging frequently" - Do you mean, the frequency with which the "Recent activity" table is updated?

Comment: @w3d I am not sure. I am writing an webapplication for 10 people tops and they will share same Gmail account(I want simple account not this groups account) and I am affraid that they will reach limits when logging from different places(same city).

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you'd reach a _numerical_ limit with 10 users (although it would be interesting to know how Gmail deals with concurrency - although maybe you are providing only limited access?). However, I imagine this might trigger the "unusual activity alert" - although this can be turned off on the account (takes a week apparently). Although, if you are writing an _application_ to interface with Gmail and your users are only connecting with your _application_, then I guess there really is only one user; your application?